# Checkbox in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I need to create a checkbox, which when selected my user is considered as ACTIVE, and when this checkbox is not selected the user is considered as INACTIVE
There's a column in my database called (is_active), and it's tinyInteger, defaults to 1, but if I click on that checkbox, it has to become 0

And I need to do this with a checkbox, my code is like this

```
<form action="/is_active/save" method="post" class="lg:text-left">
@csrf
   <div class="mb-3">
     <div class="p-6 card bordered">
         <div class="form-control">
              <input type="checkbox" name="is_active">
              <label>Active</label><br/><br/>
         </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <button type="submit"
    class="inline-flex mt-1 justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent shadow-sm text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-blue-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">
    Save
   </button>
</form>
```

My form is being directed to

```
Route::post('/is_active/save', function () {
    $userId = auth()->user()->id;

    $is_active = request('is_active');
    
    $userId->is_active = $is_active;
    $userId->save();

    return redirect("people");

})->middleware(['auth']);
```

Today this is the result I am having after saving the form

**Attempt to assign property "is_active" on int**

how do I make my checkbox change the value 1 to 0?
Someone can help me? thanks!

Comment: Checkboxes without a `value=""` when checked send "on" to the server. When unchecked, they send nothing. Additionally, you named your checkbox `terms`, so I'm not sure what `request('is_active');` is supposed to reference. If you do a `dd($request->is_active)`, what do you get?

Comment: Also, when you assign `$userId = auth()->user()->id;`, `$userId` is an integer, and you can't do `$userId->is_active`, since you can't assign properties to an integer. Your code needs a lot of refactoring...

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! already adjusted my question

Comment: Ok, you fixed the name, that's a good first step. Check the rest of my comments; you still have some issues to work out 

Comment: with dd, i get a null

Comment: That would be what you'd get if you don't check it, so that's correct now 

Comment: you may want to use $user = auth()->user()->is_active   because that is the user model where as auth()->user()->id is just the number of the user id and won't know how to update the is_active data.

Comment: Could you give me your email, or discord, or slack and help me in a chat? i'm new in this area, and i've never done this before

Comment: No, sorry, I'd prefer to keep that information separate from here. See my answer below; it should help. Also, after enough comments here, you can start a chat (a prompt will ask you to move subsequent comments to a chat to avoid unnecessary comment discussions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the default value for your Checkbox to 0:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="is_active" value="0">
```

Next, handle this value in the back end:

```php
$isActive = $request->input('is_active', 1);
```

This will result in `0` if it is checked, or `1` (the 2nd argument acts as a fallback) if you don't check it.

Lastly, assign it properly:

`routes/web.php`:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::post('/is_active/save', function (Request $request) {
  $user = auth()->user();
  $user->is_active = $request->input('is_active', 1);
  $user->save();

  return redirect('people');
})->middleware(['auth']);
```

With this code, if you don't check the checkbox, the user's `is_active` value will be set to `1`. If you do check it, the value will be set to `0`.

Comment: $isActive = $request->input('is_active', 1); Can you tell me where exactly I put this code? Would it be in the migration?

Comment: No... This has nothing to do with the migration. That code is for reference only, your complete code for this update is these 3 lines: `$user = auth()->user();`, then `$user->is_active = $request->input('is_active', 1);` and finally `$user->save();`.

Comment: I think it would be really beneficial if you look up some basic tutorials for HTML, PHP and Laravel; that syntax is pretty basic, and if you don't have a good grasp of that, you're going to struggle later on (I don't mean that in a rude way, you just need to learn to walk before you can run )

Comment: this is being the answer
Undefined variable $request

Comment: Ah, you're using `request()` instead of `$request`. Ok, 1 sec., let me update that too.

Comment: Yes of course, thanks for the help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235907/discussion-between-julia-cassemiro-and-tim-lewis).

Comment: See my update; you can "inject" `Request $request` into that function, which gives access to a `$request` variable instead of the global `request()` helper. You need to simply include it at the top of the file via `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

Answer (score 1):

In order to get a 0 if your checkbox is not checked, you could use the ternary operator like this:

```
$userId->is_active = ($request->input('terms')) ? 1 : 0;
```

The code above will result in 1 if the checkbox is **checked** and 0 if the checkbox is **not checked**

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `has` on the Request. If the checkbox isn't checked the input isn't passed at all so `has` would return `false`:

```
$user->is_active = $request->has('is_active'); // returns bool
```

Though I am not sure on the whole part about if it is checked you want it to be `0` part. I would think that would mean `1` (true) if checked.

Your error itself is from not having your User object but instead having the 'id' in a variable:

```
$user = auth()->user();
$user->is_active = ...;
```